# How to parse date from table columns

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a date from a **txt file** in such a way that i only get the ending date out of the date-range from table column.

Below is how my table in txt file looks like -

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                               |                                                                       DATE                                                                       |
|                                               |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                               |               12/23/18-01/22/19                |               11/23/18-12/22/18                |               01/23/19-02/22/19                |
|                                               |------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to simply extract the ending date i.e. `01/22/19` from first column `12/22/18` from second column and `2/22/19` from third column respectively.

Below is what i tried doing but i am not able to parse through table lines -

```
private static final Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\\s*-[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If this is SQL data, normally one uses a driver and reads the data directly.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Comment: no it is not a sql data but it is a txt file

Comment: All 3 columns are named date? Is that an sql table?

Comment: All 3 column are date but it is not a sql table. It is a txt file

Comment: What exactly does "...not able to parse through table lines" mean?  Are you getting errors? Not finding some or all occurrences?  What's going wrong? Also, it might be helpful if you could show us the coding you're using to do the searching.

Answer (score 0):

If my assmption is correct. I would simply split the 2 parts. Execute the below on all the iterations while fetching the date column from the file one by one.

```
String string = "12/23/18-01/22/19";
String[] s = string.split("-");
String date= s[1];
```

Comment: My problem is how to get hold of those dates from table columns

Comment: You can fetch the whole value from the file. And then apply split operation to get the second part in your code.

Comment: If you edit your question and add the code where you are trying to fetch the data from the file, one can help you figure out the problem.